# How do I show that this function is well defined?

Tags: general-topology, functions

I am stuck in the following problem:

> Let $X,Y$ be top. spaces and $I$ an index set. Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover for X. Moreover let $$f_i:X_i\rightarrow Y$$ be continuous functions s.t. $$f_i|_{X_i\cap X_j}=f_j|_{X_i\cap X_j}\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\, \forall i,j\in I \,\,s.t. \,\,\,X_i\cap X_j \neq \emptyset $$
> Then I defined a function $$f:X\rightarrow Y;\,\,\,f(x)=f_i(x)\,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,x\in X_i$$

I wanted to show that this is well defined, but somehow I got stuck there since I always have some problems in showing well-defindness. Could someone please help me?

Comment: If $x\in X_i$ and $x\in X_j$, then $x\in X_i \cap X_j$. So, $f(x)=f_i(x)=f_j(x)$. So every element is mapped to an unique element.

Comment: AH okey but in general is there a genral proceed how to show well defindness (as for example for injectivity and surjectivity)?

Comment: @aprozz: in this case, showing well-definedness is more or less the same as showing that $f^{-1}$ is injective and surjective.

Comment: @aprozz I dont think so, there is general method to show well-definedness.

Comment: perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a function is well defined, you need to show that every input has a unique output. For example, you might try to define a function from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2\}$ by the two functions $f_1:\{1,2\}\rightarrow \{1,2\}$ and $f_2:\{2,3\}\rightarrow \{1,2\}$ where
$$f_1(1) = 1$$
$$f_1(2) = 2$$
$$f_2(2) = 1$$
$$f_2(3) = 2$$

Notice how $f_1(2) \neq f_2(2)$. So the "function" $f$ you defined wouldn't actually be a function since it doesn't know how to assign a unique value to $2$.

Comment: so but there is not a general procedure?

Comment: The general procedure is to show that for any $x$, $f(x)$ is uniquely defined. As in my non-function example, $f(2)$ isn't defined since $f_1(2) =2$ but $f_2(2) = 1$.

Comment: A I see, thank you.